If $\overline{\varphi}: M/IM\to N/IN$ is surjective, then $\varphi: M \to N$ is surjective (without Nakayama)
This question is similar to, but not a duplicate of, my previous question: If $\overline{\varphi}: M/IM\to N/IN$ is surjective, when is $\varphi: M \to N$ surjective? .
In my Algebra I class, we were asked to show the following statement:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $I \subseteq R$ an ideal and $M$, $N$ $R$-modules. Assume furthermore that $I$ consists only of nilpotent elements and $N$ is finitely generated. If $\varphi: M \to N$ is a module homomorphism such that the induced homomorphism $\newcommand\quotient[2]{{^{\Large #1}}/{_{ \Large #2}}} \overline{\varphi}: \quotient{M}{IM} \to \quotient{N}{IN}$ is surjective, then $\varphi$ is surjective.

I know how to show this statement using Nakayama's Lemma. However, at the time, we didn't have access to Nakayama yet.
Question: Is there a proof of this statement without Nakayama?

As in the previous question, reduce to the case of $M=0$, so $IN=N$. Let $n_1,\dots,n_k$ be a generating set of $N$, and find elements $x_{ij}$ of $I$ so that
$$ n_i = \sum_j x_{ij} n_j. $$
Then if $J \subset I$ is the ideal generated by the $x_{ij}$ then $JN=N$ also. Claim that $J$ is nilpotent, which reduces this question to one you have resolved earlier (without Nakayama). Picking $l$ large enough so that $x_{ij}^l = 0$ for every $i$ and $j$, then $J^{lk^2}=0$ by the pigeonhole principle and we win.

Thank you, this is very nice!

my pleasure :-) this is a fairly common trick, which (i think? i can't seem to find any reference though) gets called resolution of the identity

I call it filtered colimits.
